# virtualbox-guest-* installed on the host; could this be the cause of system freezing?

Tags: linux-mint, freeze

I just found out that my mother had several `virtualbox` packages installed. But not `virtualbox` itself.

Namely, if I remember correctly, these three:

```
virtualbox-guest-dkms
virtualbox-guest-utils
virtualbox-guest-x11
```

And yes, these were installed on the host.

As she never used `virtualbox`, I probably installed it along with these packages long ago for testing purposes. And forgot to remove these packages along with `virtualbox` itself.

The question is:

Could this be the cause of system freezing? Well, I am unsure, if the whole system freezes. But the screen freezes almost every day. I am not at the machine, so I don't know if she could just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to restart the display manager.

She told me just now, that it happens regularly, almost daily, and she just presses the power button for a few seconds. Oh my god, I say.

So far I found these "suspects" and removed them.

Could you tell me what to look for further and where?

The system is Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple issues with this computer:

- installed guest packages on the host system; removed
- bad SSHD disk; replaced
- [swappiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) was at standard value of 60, but as this computer uses normally 6 GB of RAM and has 8 GB RAM, it was swapping like crazy; set to 1
- kernel was causing some of the issues; upgraded

Situation is now under control.